# Time series - Weird graph

Tags: time-series

with this data:

```
variable = rnorm(52, mean = 250, sd = 1)
lag.plot(variable)
```

I created a lag plot, and I am wondering if I should made some transformation to understand what happen with this series.[image]

Answer (score 2):

`lag.plot()` simply plots the value (x) and its lag (y). It is equivalent to `plot(variable[2:52],variable[1:51], type='l')`. Since your data is iid (white noise), there is no relation visible.

Comment: Hello, thank you so much for your answer. My data represents a variable with values very similar. Will you say that there is no relation visible even in that case?

Comment: Well, visually there may not be a relation. To formalize, fit the variable to its lag (i.e. AR(1) model $y_t = \beta_0 + \beta_1 y_{t-1} + \varepsilon_t$) and test $\hat \beta_1$ for significance. Also, I would recommend looking at the time series plot itself, i.e. $y$ on the y-axis and $t$ on the x-axis, not the lag plot. You can easily notice patterns with the normal plot too.